# libcurl 7.26.0 : garbage at the end of every http response

Tags: libcurl, cocos2d-x

I am using cocos2d-x game engine to develop a game. Game fetches lot of data from the server. So to reduce the loading time and data consumption , i used gzip encoding.

`curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_ACCEPT_ENCODING, "gzip,deflate");`

But strangely, i see garbage at the end of each http response and when i don't use the gzip , every http response is ok and no garbage in the end of http response.

Please suggest what can be possible reason for this issue. Your help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you find leak in XCode instruments?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
```

And

```
curl_global_cleanup();
```

after you finished sending request by `curl_easy_perform()`, then see if this error still exists.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same bug in C language with the same library.

```
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, postString);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, strlen(postString));
```

You can try to ensure that the length of POSTFIELDS is same as the POSTFIELDSIZE.